# Clamp Overlap cancels Bevel effect

Tags: faces, error, bevel

I have this table:

[image]

When I activate "Bevel", there is this incorrect face:

[image]

If I activate "Clamp Overlap" the problem disappears, but also the bevel effect:

[image]

How to solve this?

---

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your blend file, but that face should not appear with a bevel modifier so long as the underlying geometry is correct. Check for duplicate faces. If you want to upload your .blend file so we can have a look, you can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Tks, I put the file on the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is some duplicate vertices - 9 to be exact. Go to edit mode, select all, and select **Mesh > Merge By Distance**. A little window will pop up in the bottom left corner. Click to expand the little box, and press the arrow on the right side once until the value is 0.0101. They will be removed and the bevel will work cleanly.

[image: Merge]

EDIT - I'm glad the fix worked for you, but after playing with the object some more afterwards, I noticed some anomalies in the topology. Just in case, I have attached a simple .blend file with a similar table in 2 forms - The first has the original topology I used to make the table, and the second one I removed "unnecessary" (for game engines) edges, so it is reduced as far as possible
with the possible exception that I did not delete the bottom faces. Both have the same bevel modifier with the default settings. Maybe use them as a reference or comparison to see what differs between the topology of the 2 of them, and yours.

File is here - [image]

Cheers

Comment: Hang on. I'm looking more closely, and something else is weird. Give me a few mins to figure it out.

Comment: Wow, I tried to Merge vertices by distance before, but once it was showing 0 vertices I gave up. But increasing its value solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's over. You have some strange topology, I'm afraid. Are you prepping this for a game engine export? If so, it looks like something might have gone wrong when reducing your geometry. Some edges are connected, and some aren't.

Comment: That's right, it's for a game. I'm learning Blender, so there may be a lot of problems there. I'll revise all other meshes too.